# Can someone explain PPA versioning?

Tags: ppa

I have an existing software package called [gtest-runner](https://github.com/nholthaus/gtest-runner/tree/master) which I am trying to build on launchpad. I'm really confused about the versioning though.

To be clear, I've already read the versioning section of the [PPA documentation](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage).

So here's the situation:

- my software name: gtest-runner
- my software version: 1.3.1
- my Ubuntu version: 16.04

I've been calling my software `gtest-runner-1.3.1_Xubuntu16.04`, where `X` is just the iteration that I'm uploading. This seems wrong, and the lint tool is also throwing some warnings about ubuntu versions.

So what should the version in my changelog be called?

*For bonus points*

I'm new to launchpad, and unfortunately my builds are not all working, so I'm resubmitting them to try to iterate towards a working solution. Launchpad of course wants me to rev some version number, but I don't want to rev the "1.3.1" because IMO my github repo is the controlling version number.

How should I increment my versions numbers to satisfy launchpad without getting out of sync with my github versions?

Comment: If you build your own software, you can use any versioning. `1.3.1` will do.

Comment: @Pilot6 It probably would have if my initial launchpad build hadn't failed

Comment: You can remove the failed build and replace it with another one with the same version. You need to wait a bit till it actually is removed.

Comment: @Pilot6 ah, that helps!

Comment: You can use any iteration too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your own software, you can use any versioning. `1.3.1` will do.

Your changelog will be

```
gtest-runner (1.3.1) xenial; urgency=medium
```

The easiest way to increment version is to use `dch -i` command. It will add `ubuntuX` to the version. You can change the default behavior.

Comment: one comment: if you delete the ppa apparently it's important to delete the `*.source.ppa.upload` file that goes with it.

Comment: The `upload` file marks that a specific version has been uploaded. Yes, you need to delete it if you re-upload the same version.